# running python3 app at start up of Linux

Tags: python, linux, bash

I have the following script

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Welcome to auto shell" 
cd /home/pi/Desktop/Home
echo "Running the server now.....!" 
echo "*************************" |& tee -a /home/pi/Desktop/Home/logs.log
echo "Today is " |& tee -a /home/pi/Desktop/Home/logs.log
date |& tee -a /home/pi/Desktop/Home/logs.log
python3 Server.py |& tee -a  /home/pi/Desktop/Home/logs.log
```

But the output is :

```
Today is 
Sat Nov 11 01:03:46 EST 2017
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Server.py", line 1, in <module>
    import radiojavan as rj
File "/home/pi/Desktop/Home/radiojavan.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pyautogui as gui
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 115, in <module>
    from . import _pyautogui_x11 as platformModule
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyautogui/_pyautogui_x11.py", line 160, in <module>
    _display = Display(os.environ['DISPLAY'])
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 725, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'DISPLAY'
```

the app has no problem running when I manually run it by typing 
python3 Server.py

UPDATE: Clarification to the post I need the app to start running after the user pi logged in because it will need to get access to chrome

Comment: How exactly do you run it to get the error?

Comment: I removed some line breaks that looked like they shouldn't be there when I made my edit, but if they are actually in the real output, please edit them back in. Beyond that, what exactly are you asking? Depending on what you want to know, we may need to see what `Server.py` does.

Comment: The app needs to run in an XSession since it is accessing the `$DISPLAY` environment variable. What you want is not running it at boot time but at desktop login time

Comment: UPDATE: Clarification to the post I need to app to start running after the user pi logged in because it will need to get access to chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after the previous comment was made by rzzzwilson I did look into script after login and this fixed my issue

> cd /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/
>
> nano autostart

add this to the end of the file

> @/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Desktop/Home/Server.py

Answer (score 2):

At a guess you are running your failing bash script from crontab.  The environment when a program is run from crontab is very different from running it from a terminal.  One major change is that a script run at linux start doesn't have an attached terminal, hence the lack of a DISPLAY environment variable.

You are using pyautogui in your program.  That's not going to work at linux start time.  Do you really want to run the program at linux start, or do you want it run after user login to a desktop environment?